# Windows Mobile 6 and twitter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, compact-framework, twitter

I'm trying to implement Twitter into a mobile game that I'm developing and having difficulty with using the available libraries. Could someone explain how I use a library such as nTwitter on the .net compact framework 3.5 and windows mobile 6 professional SDK
Thanks in advance for any help
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Twitter can be controlled by simple authorized web requests. To do this you can use System.Net.HttpWebRequest from .NET Framework.

The example below demonstrates how to post a status to Twitter:

```
public void SubmitUserStatus(string username, string password, string tweet)
{
  // encode the username/password
  string user = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
  // determine what we want to upload as a status
  byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("status=" + tweet);
  // connect with the update page
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml");
  // set the method to POST
  request.Method = "POST";
  request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
  // set the authorisation levels
  request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + user);
  request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  // set the length of the content
  request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
  // set up the stream
  Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
  // write to the stream
  reqStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
  // close the stream
  reqStream.Close();
}
```

source: http://weblogs.asp.net/wallym/archive/2009/03/25/twitter-api-submit-a-post-in-c.aspx

Also I would recommend to look at this page for ready libraries: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#csharp